# How to solve strange behavior of internet on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet

I know question isn't good, but it hard to explain it in one question.

I have home WiFi network and two computers. On first computer (Windows XP) everything is okay. I turn a browser (Chrome, I checked on IE9 too), I can get in to every website.

On second computer (Windows 7) I turn browser (I tested chrome, ie, mozilla), I can browse google.com, but when I want to get in to other website I can't. Browser just blocks. It loads all the time, but nothing happens. When I back to google or I write in field google address it gets in to website. I can search on google. It's like "something" pass google domain but other not.

What it the funniest for me, that I used console and pinged other websites, which I try to get in by browser, and I have respondes from all the sites.

Comment: I had this same thing, but I use a lot of screwey stuff, so if your ready try these Oddball things. Ping 5 addresses that you know are pingable by Name (and wont knock you out) EX: Yahoo.com Google.com Superuser.com Broadbandreports.com whois.com Bad example: amazon, or ebay (they dont allow).  While your pinging the names write down or copy the IP numbers.  go back and ping all 5 by numbers.  Now, do the same thing using these additional parmeters.  Ping -l 400 .  ok after that  add 4 also  Ping -4 -l 400.  If you dont know why just supply what happens, if you do know why, then your 1/2there.

Comment: -l doesnt show well in the text here.  just to confirm that is L as in Letter, but it must be lower case.

Comment: The Why. might seems crasy, and there are better ways I am sure. 1)your testing DNS, are the names resolving, if not are the numbers resolving. Is it slow to do the first name resolve. 2) Your testing packet fragmentation, or what I call sending a 15foot truck under a 14foot bridge.   3) Your testing without IP6 through the devices. . . Now you know the other half.  Which just leaves telling at least basically what your results are.  . . Notes, to get the numbers to ping without DNS, use some other computer that has DNS working.